# Cannot open TIFF due to missing codec in R w/ raster library

Tags: raster, r, rgdal, compression

Title explains my predicament. I cannot open a tiff file using the raster package and receive an error that tells me it is due to a missing codec:

**Code:**

```
library(rgdal)    
library(raster)
file_name <- "C:\\path\\to\\raster.tif"
r <- raster(file_name)
```

**Output:**

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
  C:\\path\\to\\raster.tif: Cannot open TIFF file due to missing codec.

Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
```

**Raster Compression Info:**

```
Compression Type: ZSTD
Interleave: Band
Predictor Level: 3
```

Raster was created and compressed using gdal GTIFF driver and Creation Options API in Python

Comment: It seems that the reading GDAL is not built as required https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#creation-options "ZSTD is available since GDAL 2.3 when using internal libtiff and if GDAL built against libzstd >=1.0, or if built against external libtiff with zstd support." If you can rewrite the TIFFs try DEFLATE or LZW compression.

Comment: Converting the raster compression type to DEFLATE fixed the issue. Thank you!